# Joomla 4 create article programmatically

Tags: php, articles, mysql, joomla-4.x

I have tried a few ways to create articles programmatically in Joomla 4, but none of my attempts are working.

First is to insert data by mysql using `$db->getQuery(true)` -- the article shows in the database, but not in the admin dashboard.

```
$insert = $db->getQuery(true);
$columns = array('asset_id', 'title', 'alias', 'introtext', 'fulltext', 'state', 'catid', 'created', 'created_by', 'created_by_alias',
'modified', 'modified_by', 'images', 'urls', 'attribs', 'metadata', 'metadesc', 'language');
$values = array(0, $db->quote($title), $db->quote($alias), $db->quote($introtext), $db->quote($fulltext), $db->quote($state), $db->quote($catid), $db->quote(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")), $db->quote($created_by), $db->quote($created_by_alias),
$db->quote($modified), $db->quote($modified_by), $db->quote($images), $db->quote($urls), $db->quote($attribs), $db->quote($metadata), $db->quote(""), $db->quote("*"));

$insert
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__content'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
    ->values(implode(',', $values));
$db->setQuery($insert);
$db->execute();
```

Second is using JTable, but it says error `failed to start application`.

```
$table = JTable::getInstance('Content', 'JTable', array());
$data = array(
    'catid' => 1,
    'title' => 'SOME TITLE',
    'introtext' => 'SOME TEXT',
    'fulltext' => 'SOME TEXT',
    'state' => 1,
);
if (!$table->bind($data)){
    $this->setError($table->getError());
    return false;
}
if (!$table->check()){
    $this->setError($table->getError());
    return false;
}
if (!$table->store()){
    $this->setError($table->getError());
    return false;
}
```

How should I create articles programmatically in Joomla 4?

Comment: If you use this method, the historic of changes of the article is updated ? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I rewrote the "[Content Uploader](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/content-uploader/)" for Joomla 4 because I couldn't reach the developer. I had exactly the same problem as you described in the first example.

The reason is that the Workflow component does not display the article if there is no entry for this article. So you have to make an entry in the table #__workflow_associations, otherwise it won't work.

So I added the following code in which I make such an entry:

```
// define values
$ID = $results[0]->id;
$stageID = 1;
$extenstion = "'com_content.article'";

// makes an entry so that the article is visible in the backend
$query = $this->db->getQuery(true);
            
$colums = array('item_id', 'stage_id', 'extension');
$values = array($ID, $stageID, $extenstion);

$query  
    ->insert('#__workflow_associations')
    ->columns($colums)
    ->values(implode(',', $values));

$this->db->setQuery($query);
$this->db->execute();
```

Here is the link to my [original file](https://gitlab.com/gratia-mira-opensource/spreadsheet-data-uploader/-/blob/main/source/admin/src/Helper/Tasks.php#L627) on GitLab. And here to the [ticket](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/36421) that I made on the GitHub account of Joomla.

However, it is better to use the "article model" class. Note the example: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/32345/16394

Comment: Ahh yes, I tried to find in many tables to look any relationship, but didn't expect it to be the __workflow_associations table :) thank you very much!!

Answer (score 6):

This will work.

```
$newapp = JFactory::getApplication();
$mvcFactory = $newapp->bootComponent('com_content')->getMVCFactory();
$articleModel = $mvcFactory->createModel('Article', 'Administrator', ['ignore_request' => true]);

$article = [
    'catid' => 2,
    'alias' => 'tttttttttttttttt44',
    'title' => '123My Article Title 44',
    'introtext' => 'My Article Intro Text',
    'fulltext' => 'My Article Full Text',
    'state' => 1,
    'language' => '*',
];

if (!$articleModel->save($article)){
    throw new Exception($articleModel->getError());
}
```

Comment: Please always try to include some explanation or supporting references with your advised snippets.  "Use this" answers miss a great opportunity to educate/empower the asker and future researchers.

Comment: How do we get the id of the newly created article?

Comment: If you use this method, the historic of changes of the article is updated ?

Thanks